# c++ win32: how to set back color of a window?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I can set the back color when i am registering the class, e.g.:

```
wincl.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(202, 238, 255));
RegisterClassEx(&wincl);
```

But how would i do it to any window i have created with the CreateWindow function?
like a button on my main window, i have visual styles enabled, and i can notice the windows default gray back color behind the button.

Don't tell me i have to SetWindowLong for the window procedure on allllllll my controls and intercept the WM_PAINT :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the windows controls send a message to their parent to get the brush to use to fill their background.
Assuming you save a copy of the brush handle somewhere, you can do the following in your WindowProc, or DialogProc, to ensure everything draws with the correct background brush.

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
  HDC hdc;
  HWND hwndCtl;
  POINT pt;
  hdc = (HDC)wParam;
  hwndCtl = (HWND)lParam;
  pt.x = 0;
  pt.y = 0;
  MapWindowPoints(hwndCtl,_hwnd,&pt,1);
  x = -pt.x;
  y = -pt.y;
  SetBrushOrgEx(hdc,x,y,NULL);
  return (INT_PTR)_skinBrush;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a customized window you can create your own window class to draw that type of window. Implement a handler for wm_paint and draw whatever you want for the window. There are a lot of tutorials available.