# How can I set hbrBackground to a solid color of my choosing?

Tags: c, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ win32: how to set back color of a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301053/c-win32-how-to-set-back-color-of-a-window)

I don't want to use on of the stock HBRUSH's in WNDCLASS

Here is my WNDCLASS:

```
 WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

 wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
 wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
 wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
 wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
 wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
 wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
 wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
 wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (BLACK_BRUSH) ;
 wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
 wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;
```

I want the hbrBackground member to be hex value #cfdf9b

```
wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (#cfdf9b);
```

With this there errors come

**error C2014: preprocessor command must start as first nonwhite space
warning C4047: 'function' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'LPCSTR'
helloworldwinapi.c(21) : warning C4024: 'GetStockObject' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'**

Comment: Hex constant in C : 0xNNNNN, but that won't get what you want. you need to create a brush using the proper GDI apis, then set that to your hbrBackground. There are some exceptions to this. system color indexes cast to HBRUSH also work (i.e. COLOR_WINDOW+1, COLOR_BTNFACE+1, etc). Read more about the WNDCLASS struct and hbrBackground, and check out CreateSolidBrush() in the api documentation.

Comment: ahaaa. 
HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(207,223,155));
wndclass.hbrBackground = hBrush;

Comment: @SnuffMovie don't forget to get back the brush, replacing it with a stock brush and DeleteObject()'ing the allocated one when finished with it. If this is a perma-brush (i.e. there until the app goes down) i wouldn't worry about it, but its always good practice to do it right.